# django filter regex - failing to match whitespace

Tags: regex, django

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
                Q(title__iregex=r'.{10,}.*') |
                Q(title__iregex=r'.*[0-9].*') |
                Q(title__iregex=r'\s+')
                )
```

I am getting all objects whose `titles are longer than 10` or whose `titles contain at least one number`.

but the `Q(title__iregex=r'\s+')` is failing which should return objects whose titles contain at least one whitespace. what am I doing wrong?

I tried:

```
r'[\\s+]'
r'.*[\\s+].*'
r'\\s+'
r'[:space:]'
```

no sign of success.

I am using MySQL btw

Comment: Not an answer, but have a look at https://regex101.com/#python -- at a glance your regex seems correct, so maybe there's a setting somewhere for how the regex is interpreted that's off?

Comment: So, you have not tried `Q(title__iregex=r'.*\s+.*')`?

Answer (score 3):

ok problem solved. Since MySQL POSIX Regex uses, I needed:

```
Q(answer__iregex=r'[[:space:]]')
```

Comment: Yeah, it should, because you mention you are using MySQL (I have not noticed that before). Acc. to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, these character classes must be used inside `[]`. You can accept your own answer, BTW. I just wonder if you could also use `[[:blank:]]`...

Comment: @stribizhev http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html  yes, I could use blank, but it only matches space and tab. I wonder now what the POSIX version for ``r'.{10,}.*'``.

Comment: Acc. to http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html, `r'.\{10,\}.*'` if you have to deal with POSIX BRE. For POSIX ERE, `r'.{10,}.*'` must be valid. Else, if there is a problem with the undefined max count, try a workaround with `.{10,10000}`.